# Solr long term storage, or export function

Tags: solr, storage

Our Solr application adds about 1 GiB of data to the Solr index daily. The application only accesses the last N days' data, however all the data must be saved for future features. To save space on the main server (expensive) I would like to export the data and save it on local storage (cheap). MySQL has the wonderful `mysqldump` feature which makes the data easy to export and import as per need. Does Solr have a similar feature that can be activated without shutting down the Solr application?

The specific critical features that I am interested in:

1. Works while Solr is running, no downtime.
2. Export subset of data, such as `datetime:[1356220800 TO 1356393600]`
3. Import the data

The specific non-critical features that I am interested in:

1. Ability to search the exported data to find a subset to insert (using either common GNU tools such as `grep` or a small standalone tool.
2. Intrinsic data compression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check upon :-

- Solr [backup](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication#HTTP_API) - Will allow you the backup the index on the same server. You can reuse the index as it is a full fledged Solr Index
- [Replication](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication) - You can replicate every periodically and maintain the index on a different Solr server. This is basically export and import both as it needs Solr running and would be hosted for you to use.
- You can always use the [Delete](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_documents_by_ID_and_by_Query) query to delete (all records before the date) the data from Solr.

In Addition

- There is no time specific export or dump functionality. However, you
  can perform the above daily, weekly and you would have only the data
  within that period.
- All the above would work on Solr without any
  downtime.
- The index can be query with other Solr instance or [Luke](http://www.getopt.org/luke/).